# Multiple conditional Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get students who fulfill the following criteria in a WPF application-

1. Are "passed" the examination
2. Except first "passed" student in each "group" (Example: Group 1 & 3)
3. If a group contains only one "passed" student, that student should be omitted (Example: Group 2)
4. Original grouping should be preserved

Please refer this [Students collection](https://ibb.co/rHNd6bh) as I don't find any option to create tables in StackOverflow.

**Code** I tried-

```
 var results = myList
                 .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Status)
                 .Where(g => g.Status == "Passed")
                 .Skip(1)
                 .ToList();
```

**The Problem:**
This doesn't omit the first "passed" student in each group. Instead, it omits only "Richard" (in Group 1) in the entire collection.

Comment: The real problem is that your current code can't even compile, because there's a missing `)` - opened here `.Select(` and never closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's try to apply conditions one after one:

```
var result = myList
  .Where(student => student.Status == "Passed") // passed only
  .GroupBy(student => student.GroupId)          // grouped by Group Id
  .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1))           // Skip 1st student in each group 
  .ToList();                                    // if we want to have a List
```

If

> "If a group contains only one "passed" student, that student should be
>   omitted"

means that we should skip 1st student in each group except groups with *single* student:

```
var result = myList
  .Where(student => student.Status == "Passed") 
  .GroupBy(student => student.GroupId)          
  .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(group.Count() > 1 ? 1 : 0))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Did YoKidYo write, and Dmitry read "*that student should be omitted*" as "*that student should**n't** be omitted*"? Or is my understanding of "*omitted*" wrong?

Comment: No @Rafalon, he read it right. That student should be omitted.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if he should be omitted, isn't it the same as skipped? Which would mean you skip 1 regardless the `Count`?

Comment: You're right, it's the same as skip. But my own code applied Skip parameter to entire collection, instead of Groups.

Comment: Therefore, `group.Count() > 1 ? 1 : 0` should be `1`

Comment: Thank you so much @Rafalon. You was very much right. I just checked and found that group.Count() > 1 ? 1 : 1 should have been used instead.

Comment: @YoKidYo Well that works, but it's the same as `1` alone (just remove the whole `group.Count() > 1 ? 1 : 1` and write `1` instead -> `Skip(1)`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207563/discussion-between-yokidyo-and-rafalon).

Answer (score 1):

Do the Skip in the select so it applies to each group, not the overall results:

```
 var results = myList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                    .Where(g => g.Status == "Passed")
                    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Status).Skip(1))                 
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: `.Where(g => g.Status == "Passed")` doesn't work, you have a `IEnumberable` of items within that group so you need to filter `.Where(g => g.All(y => y.Status == "Passed"))` or filter it prior like Dmitry did